# LINQ to SQL left outer join

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a table called payroll which has a field called payrollId. I also have a table called EmpMasterPayroll that has a field called payrollId. I want to collect all the records from payroll that are not present in EmpMasterPayroll.

In pure sql terms this can be done this way:

Select p.* from Payroll p left outer join EmpMasterPayroll e on e.payrollId = p.payrollId.

Can anyone write the LINQ to SQL translation of this. I have a data context called dcPayroll.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: "I want to collect all the records from payroll that are not present in EmpMasterPayroll." Thats not what left (outer) join does. Left join makes sure that all entries from the left table are included, if there is an corresponding entry in the right table or not.

Comment: Your SQL doesn't make sense, its the same as "SELECT p.* FROM Payroll p". See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all entries from Payroll which dont have an entry in EmpMasterPayroll, this should work:

```
from p in dcPayroll.Payroll
where p.MasterPayroll == null
select p;
```

I am assuming here that you have a linq to sql association between the two tables and the child table is named "MasterPayroll".

Alternative:

```
from p in dcPayroll.Payroll
where !(from mp in dcPayroll.MasterPayroll select mp.payrollid).Contains(p.payrollid)
select p;
```

Comment: Thanks, that can work. Unfortunately that is not possible in this case. Can you tell me how I can write a LINQ to SQL query.

Comment: Why is it not possible? Try out the alternative solution I added.